# How to pass a type String variable to HttpPost?

Tags: java, eclipse, http-post, httpclient

I'm working in Java and trying to form a URL using concatenated strings.  This then gets passed to HttpPost as the URI to POST to.

This code fails:

```
String str1 = "http://www.example.com";
String str2 = "/directory";

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(str1 + str2);
```

This also fails:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(str1.concat(str2));
```

As does this:

```
String strCombined = str1 + str2;
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strCombined);
```

However, This works:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/directory");
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:  Stacktrace:

```
05-31 01:43:29.973: W/System.err(451): java.net.UnknownHostException: http
05-31 01:43:29.983: W/System.err(451):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
05-31 01:43:29.993: W/System.err(451):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
05-31 01:43:29.993: W/System.err(451):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
05-31 01:43:30.003: W/System.err(451):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
05-31 01:43:30.013: W/System.err(451):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-31 01:43:30.013: W/System.err(451):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-31 01:43:30.024: W/System.err(451):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
05-31 01:43:30.033: W/System.err(451):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-31 01:43:30.043: W/System.err(451):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-31 01:43:30.043: W/System.err(451):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Comment: "Fails" is non-descriptive.   Do they all "fail" the same way?  Can you post what the failure (Exception) is?

Comment: You're missing additional info that would help us diagnose the problem--the string value passed to the ctor would be the same in all cases.

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing, which probably is the problem I am having.  The string value _should_ be the same in each case - but it isn't behaving that way.

Comment: I really doubt it fails just because you are concatenating strings, try making a new URL and pass the string to it. Then pass the URL to the HTTPPost. See if it works.

Comment: The stack trace isn't from calling the constructor. Show us a little more code please.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this not something we can expect, right? Then what could be the reason troubling you here..
The codes you have shared with us may be a simplified version( for better readability ) and not your actual code, right? That makes me feel you may be having a typo or any other simple mistake in your actual code, which could be much more complicated ( and hard to find simple mistakes/typos/errors ).

This may be a method or a constructor,like

```
public HttpPost getConnection(String str1){
 String strCombined = this.domain+ str1;
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strCombined);
}
```

Fisrt thing I would do in a case like this is, print the strCombined before giving it to the HttpPost constructor and see if it is what I really expects.

```
public HttpPost getConnection(String str1){
 String strCombined = this.domain+ str1;
 System.out.print("strCombined : "+strCombined);
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strCombined);
}
```

This may be a simple part of a multi threaded application, then you have to make sure this method is  thread safe!